# Numpy slicing python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, object-slicing

I have 4 arrays. **Array X**: is 2D array that contain examples (each has 3 features):

```
X = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21]])
```

**Array Y** contains labels for examples in  **Array X**:

```
Y = array([11, 44, 77, 22, 77, 22, 22])
```

**Arrays L & R** contain subsets of the labels

```
L = array([11, 44])
R = array([77, 22])
```

I want to slice both X and Y according to the labels in L and R. So the output should be:

```
XL = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
XR = array([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21]])
YL = array([11, 44])
YR = array([77, 22, 77, 22, 22])
```

I know I can do something like the following to extract the rows I want when based on value:

```
Y[Y==i]
X[Y[Y==i], :]
```

**However, `i` here is a value, but in my question it is another array (e.g., `L` and `R`).**
I want an efficient solution in python 3 to do that. Any hints?

Comment: what sort of label is `44` and `77`? Do you mean to use it as `X[3, 3]` and `X[6, 6]`?

Comment: This is not what is called slicing. Its boolean indexing, quite different... Unless your labels are organized in a very particular way, you just can't use mere slicing.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis these are values correspond to some sort of classes. There might be another labels like 55, 66, 99, etc.

Comment: @Julien I see! so is there a way to do what I want using the boolean indexing?

Comment: Yes and it looks like what you just did, if you are not happy with your code, you need to share it and explain what exactly you are unhappy with...

Comment: I didn't do it! I need a way to do it.

Comment: `for i in L: X[Y[Y==i]]` + some `np.vstack, hstack etc`...

Comment: @Julien this will not work since the values of L are not indices: IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7

Comment: Just copied your own typo: use `X[Y==i]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
import numpy as np

X = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21]])
Y = np.asarray([11, 44, 77, 22, 77, 22, 22])

L = np.asarray([11, 44])
R = np.asarray([77, 22])

mask_L = np.isin(Y, L)
mask_R = np.isin(Y, R)

print(X[mask_L,:])  # output: array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

print(X[mask_R,:])  # output: array([[ 7,  8,  9], [10, 11, 12], 13, 14, 15], 16, 17, 18], 19, 20, 21]])

print(Y[mask_L])  # output: array([11, 44])

print(Y[mask_R])  # output: array([77, 22, 77, 22, 22])
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how you normally do:

```
from numpy import array

X = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21]])
Y = array([11, 44, 77, 22, 77, 22, 22])

L = array([11, 44])
R = array([77, 22])

XL = array([x for x, y in zip(X, Y) if y in L])
XR = array([x for x, y in zip(X, Y) if y in R])
YL = array([y for y in Y if y in L])
YR = array([y for y in Y if y in R])

# Output
# XL = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
# XR = array([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21]])
# YL = array([11, 44])
# YR = array([77, 22, 77, 22, 22])
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: while this is "clean and convenient" it is probably quite slow on big data, since it's looping in python heavily instead of using numpy vectorization...